# How do you control placement of different images inside the same DIV with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know this should be simple but I can't seem to make it work.  I have six boxes with info with icon images that I made into a list.  I use div# li img to control the placement of the icons.  But on the last box there is an Icon img and then four small social media icon images.  I can't figure out how to control the social media icon img placement (the padding) since the div# li img overrides it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target truly ancient browsers that don't support `>` as well, you can use a more specific selector to override it:

```
#grid li a img {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `#grid li > img` in order to select only images that are children of the `li`.  The social media icons are younger descendants.

Comment: sorry not sure I understand, that is new to me, is that the actual code?

Comment: @user1269988 yes, `>` is the child selector (a child is an immediate descendant).  It will select `<li><img>` but not `<li><a><img>`

Answer (score 0):

You can still add `style` attribute to `li` and can controle the `padding` for images